# Is there a way to easily run the same query in Toad against multiple Oracle database servers?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have several servers hosting data for the same application, and I want to see the results of the same query from different servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Script Manager to run one or more queries/scripts against multiple servers/databases.

Toad for Data Analysts has a Group execute feature built into the editor, which I personally prefer over the Script Manager.

You can learn more at [Toad Executing Scripts against Multiple Databases](http://www.toadworld.com/BLOGS/tabid/67/EntryId/257/Toad-Executing-Scripts-against-Multiple-Databases-Part-1.aspx).

Comment: Here's a link to see how the Group Execute works
 http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2010/06/introducing-toad-for-sql-server-part-1/